# Create a query to get sum

Tags: sql

Need to fetch sum of column based on condition.I uploaded the query here I am getting an error

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

QUERY:

```sql
SELECT 'TON'=(select PC_Mark_ID,
SUM(CAST(PC_ItemTotalTONWeight as float)) AS TON  FROM tb_StructureDelivery WHERE PC_Item_Description 
NOT LIKE '%Handrid%' AND PC_Item_Description 
NOT LIKE '%Stair%' AND PC_Item_Description 
NOT LIKE '%Grating%' AND PC_Item_Description 
NOT LIKE '%Ladder%' AND PC_Item_Description 
NOT LIKE '%Bolt%' AND PC_Item_Description 
NOT LIKE '%Nut%'GROUP BY PC_Mark_ID) ,'TON'=(select PC_Mark_ID,
SUM(CAST(PC_ItemTotalTONWeight as float)) AS TON1  FROM tb_StructureDelivery WHERE PC_Item_Description 
LIKE '%Handrid%' AND PC_Item_Description 
LIKE '%Stair%' AND PC_Item_Description 
LIKE '%Grating%' AND PC_Item_Description 
LIKE '%Ladder%' GROUP BY PC_Mark_ID) 
FROM tb_StructureDelivery GROUP BY PC_Mark_ID
```

I need to calculate the difference between the 2 queries.Kindly help.

Comment: You want the difference of TON and TON1?

Comment: yes i need the difference of 2 values too in another column

Comment: for eg we have the table with values below

ID     DESC  TON_WEIGHT
1 BEAM  15
1 HAND  10
1 BEAM  5
2 HAND  5

RESULT

ID  TON  TON
1 20  10
2 5  0

Comment: don't you think, using '%Bolt%' and '%Nut%' conditions only in query will give you the value, like - `select PC_Mark_ID,
SUM(CAST(PC_ItemTotalTONWeight as float)) AS TON  FROM tb_StructureDelivery WHERE PC_Item_Description NOT LIKE '%Bolt%' AND PC_Item_Description 
NOT LIKE '%Nut%'GROUP BY PC_Mark_ID` so TON will be the required difference, why you need to queries?

Comment: If we run the query mentioned by Abhay will reterive the datas.But I need to incoporate both values in same query to display in reports.I need the difference to be include.

Answer (score 0):

I think (caveat, no data available to test this on!) you should be able to use a CTE to define both criteria and then use a full join between them and calclulate the variance. Probably you can do this in a single query but not possible to say without actually seeing the data.

```
with t1 as (
select PC_Mark_ID, Sum(Cast(PC_ItemTotalTONWeight as float)) as TON 
from tb_StructureDelivery
where PC_Item_Description not like '%Handrid%' 
and PC_Item_Description not like '%Stair%' 
and PC_Item_Description not like '%Grating%' 
and PC_Item_Description not like '%Ladder%' 
and PC_Item_Description not like '%Bolt%' 
and PC_Item_Description not like '%Nut%'
group by PC_Mark_ID
), t2 as (
select PC_Mark_ID, Sum(Cast(PC_ItemTotalTONWeight as float)) as TON1
from tb_StructureDelivery 
where PC_Item_Description like '%Handrid%' 
and PC_Item_Description like '%Stair%' 
and PC_Item_Description like '%Grating%' 
and PC_Item_Description like '%Ladder%' 
group by PC_Mark_ID
)
select Coalesce(t1.PC_Mark_ID,t2.PC_Mark_ID) PC_Mark_ID, Coalesce(t1.TON,0)-Coalesce(t2.TON1,0) Diff
from t1 full join t2 on t1.PC_Mark_ID=t2.PC_Mark_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the query will check  and update

Comment: That's great! If it helped you out feel free to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0):

As the aggregation is just on PC_Mark_ID each value can calculated in a single select statement - and the difference can be derived from the initial common table expression

```
with [cte_TON_TON1] as (
select [PC_Mark_ID]
     , [TON] = SUM(case when  PC_Item_Description NOT LIKE '%Handrid%'
                             AND PC_Item_Description NOT LIKE '%Stair%' 
                             AND PC_Item_Description NOT LIKE '%Grating%' 
                             AND PC_Item_Description NOT LIKE '%Ladder%' 
                             AND PC_Item_Description NOT LIKE '%Bolt%' 
                             AND PC_Item_Description NOT LIKE '%Nut%' 
                             then cast(PC_ItemTotalTONWeight as float)
                         else 0.0 end )
     , [TON1] =  SUM(case when PC_Item_Description LIKE '%Handrid%' 
                           AND PC_Item_Description LIKE '%Stair%'
                           AND PC_Item_Description LIKE '%Grating%' 
                           AND PC_Item_Description LIKE '%Ladder%' 
                        then cast(PC_ItemTotalTONWeight as float)
                         else 0.0 end )
  from tb_StructureDelivery
 group by [PC_Mark_ID]
 )
 select [PC_Mark_ID], [TON], [TON1] , [Diff] = [TON] - [TON1] 
   from [cte_TON_TON1]
```